# How do I update GNOME extensions installed from Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-software

All my extensions are installed from the software center and today I installed the extensions update notifier and found there were a couple of extensions having updates, seems like the software center does not update the extensions nor notify the user about that. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Gnome Extensions are updated via [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/). Just visit the site, click on the 'Installed Extensions' tab at the top and update as needed. I have a link somewhere in my favorites that explains this and two options (one github user, and an extension that notifies you when extensions are available)... trying to grab that now.
[Found it](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/how-to-update-gnome-extensions)!

Comment: Just to remind, you need to open the page in a browser that includes the [gnome shell integration extension](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your extensions using a terminal you could also use [this](https://github.com/brunelli/gnome-shell-extension-installer) script.

Install it by running:

```
sudo apt install curl
wget -O gnome-shell-extension-installer "https://github.com/brunelli/gnome-shell-extension-installer/raw/master/gnome-shell-extension-installer"
chmod +x gnome-shell-extension-installer
sudo mv gnome-shell-extension-installer /usr/bin/
```

Then you can update your extensions with `gnome-shell-extension-installer --update`.

If you want to update your extensions automatically after every reboot, install the following systemd timer and service:

```
user=$(whoami)

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/gnome-shell-extension-updater.service > /dev/null
[Unit]
Description=Update all Gnome Shell Extensions

[Service]
User=$user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gnome-shell-extension-installer --update
EOF

cat <<EOF| sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/gnome-shell-extension-updater.timer > /dev/null
[Unit]
Description=Update Gnome Shell Extensions after every boot

[Timer]
OnBootSec=5m

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
EOF

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable gnome-shell-extension-updater.timer
```

These commands will create a `systemd.timer` and a `systemd.service`. The timer will run the service to update your extensions five minutes after every boot. You can adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Shell extensions that have been installed using the software center are system wide updated from the Ubuntu repositories just like all other software on your system. By design, and similar to other applications in a Ubuntu system, the extensions will not necessarily be updated to newer versions that have been published upstream.

- System wide extensions are supported by the Ubuntu developpers. If **stability of your operating system** is of prime concern, trust the Ubuntu developpers, who will push an updated version only if critical errors or vulnerabilities are present.
- If you want and need the **latest and newest**, then indeed feel free to install support to install extensions from the gnome shell extension website (not installed by default). This is zhere you take control yourself. Extensions installed that way are installed for your user only. Extensions installed this way are not supported, so occasionally, an update may not work or have other issues.